# Find the solution of $p^2 + q^2 =1$ that passes through the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=1$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of $p^2 + q^2 =1$ that passes through the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=1$.

Here,

$$p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$ and $$q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

Using Charpit's method, we can find the general solution to be,

$$z=ax+y\sqrt{1-a^2}+b$$

where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants.

What should I do to find out the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the solution passes through the required circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\quad z=ax+y\sqrt{1-a^2}+b\quad$ is a particular set of solutions of the PDE. But it is not the general solution because the general solution involves two arbitrary functions (not only two arbitrary constants).

In fact, there is no need for the general solution, since a simple inpection gives the obvious particular solution : 
$$z(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$p=z_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\quad$ and $\quad q=z_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\quad\to\quad p^2+q^2=z_x^2+z_y^2=1$

On the circle $\quad x^2+y^2=1\quad$ we get $z=\sqrt{1}=1\quad$ Thus, this circle belongs to the solutions of the PDE.

Comment: Is there a methodical approach to solve these problems as opposed to solution by inspection?

Comment: The method of characteristics of course. An almost identical example of solving can be found in :  https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/436.A1.12f/PDE_Meth_Characteristics.pdf : Example 2.26 ,  equation (2.208).  Except the condition along $x^2+y^2=1$ is $u=0$ instead of $u=1$. The method and calculus are well detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $a=\sin\alpha$, $\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}=\cos\alpha$, the condition that the solution passes through a point $(x,y,z)=(\sin\phi,\cos\phi,1)$ reads
$$\cos\alpha\cos\phi+\sin\alpha\sin\phi+b=1, $$
i.e.,
$$ b=1-\cos(\alpha-\phi).$$
As $\phi$ can be arbitrary, we arrive at $$0\le b\le 2. $$

Comment: But there are still two arbitrary constants - $\alpha$ and $\phi$. The general solution also has two constants. One of them should get eliminated due to the constraint, right?